# PostgreSQL - session recovery?

Tags: pgadmin, recovery

I have just had a power outage while working on some complex queries using PostgreSQL and pgAdmin 4. Is there any way I can restore the session and get the queries the same way other systems do?

Comment: If you wrote your queries in pgAdmin you should be able to open a new query window on the same database and at the top of that query window there should be a drop down box where you can find previous queries.

Comment: I can't find the dropdown you speak of. I am on pgAdmin 4.

Comment: Hm ok. I only know PgAdmin3 but maybe this link helps you: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/1.x/query_tool.html

Comment: I found it in a tab called Query History just to the right of the Query tab

Answer (score 2):

If your

- log level is high enough they'll be in the log
- Or, if [using PgAdmin,](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/options-query_tool.html)

  > History file path - The History file path specifies the path to the Query tool’s history file. The default file name is pgadmin_histoqueries.xml; you can use the Browse button to open a file browser and modify the location of the file.

Shy of that no. And, that's not really *session recovery*. It's just seeing the last executed commands.

Comment: I don't get the impression pgAdmin4 works the same way with query history. Taking a look right now...

Comment: The history worked for me. Thank you!